# Advice on this Angular + ngRx (effects) - what about websocket events?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

So I'm experimenting with ngrx & ngrx/effects by building the following sandbox:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-vanilla

Quick intro:

- it has a root store in app/store
- it has lazy loading of two modules in app/features
- it has singleton services in app/commons

Three pages:

- action items: routing to this pages triggers a random generation of three goofy corporate action items
- users: a basic master > detail redux implementation with router support
- meeting: the place that raises my question, click the "start meeting" to witness a relevant exchange of ideas.

Question & context:

- I understand all data updates in redux are to happen via actions
- the "effects" library is to handle async events in order to dispatch new actions based on 3rd party events and async calls.
- the app/common/meeting/service imitates the behavior of for instance a websocket or a firebase realtime DB pushing updates.

Upon receiving an update (illustrated in app/store/effects/meeting.effects.ts), a new action is dispatched.

Finally, the question: Is it a clean practice to have a a common service know about the store? Where is the best place to register a listener to a websocket / firebase realtime db in order to dispatch actions upon data being pushed?

Here, I made it so that an effect (meeting.effects) reacts upon the meetingActions.START_MEETING action type and whenever data is pushed, dispatch an update order to the store, but this feels wrong for a series of reasons I come up with:

- Hard to unit test in isolation (needs more context than itself)
- In case of a "stop meeting" action, this approach needs to store a Subscription (or?) in order to stop the subscription. In my approach, there's no control over the observable being created in the wilderness.

How are such cases usually handled?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming `websocket` is emitting different kinds of events, map each event to different actions in a `websocket` service like

```js
@Injectable()
class WebsocketService{
    private socket$:Observable<Action>
    getActions():Observable<Action>{
        if(!this.socket$) {
           this.socket$ = Observable.webSocket(url).pipe(
               map(functionToMapActions)
            ,shareReplay(1)
           );
        }
        return this.socket$;
    }
}
```

where `functionToMapActions` maps webSocket events to actions, and I suggest adding [`shareReplay`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-shareReplay) operator at the end so that we read webSocket only once.

the [`Observable.webSocket`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-webSocket) connects to webSocket, and emits events as they arrive

webSocket connection will be established when you subscribe to `webService.getActions()`

You can subscribe to websocket actions in `@Effects` initialization [see here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/api.md#initializing-effect)

```js
@Effect()
init$ = this.websocketService.getActions();
```

this will emit all actions as soon as your app starts (if the effect is in the root module) or your module is loaded if it is in the lazy loaded module;

Or if you are interested in a limited set of actions you can do like this

```js
@Effect()
init$ = this.websocketService.getActions().pipe(filter(filterNeededActionsHere));
```

you can also start listening to actions only after a particular event like this

```js
@Effect()
init$ = this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType('Event which marks start')
          ,swichMapTo(this.websocketService.getActions())
     );
```

like the previous example, you can also filter out the action here sane as before

hope this answers your question

Answer (score 2):

NgRx v9 changed syntax a little. Use following code for *root-level* effects class:

```
init$ = createEffect(() => 
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
    // websocket events handling logic
    switchMap(() => webSocketEvents$)
  )
);
```

This is just slightly adapted example from the [Docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#root_effects_init).

If you work with feature-level effect class, `ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT` won't work, you need to use `OnRunEffects` lifecycle hook:

```
class UserEffects implements OnRunEffects  {
  ngrxOnRunEffects(resolvedEffects$: Observable<EffectNotification>) {
    // websocket events handling logic
    return webSocketEvents$.pipe(
      exhaustMap(() => resolvedEffects$)
    );
  }
}
```

More detailed example is in the [Docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#onruneffects).

`webSocketEvents$` in both examples is an `Observable` that can be constructed using one of the rxjs functions:

```
webSocket(socketUrl) // if you want to manage websocket connection via rxjs
fromEvent(socketIoClient) // useful if websocket connection handled by socket.io-client
```

Answer (score 1):

A custom example of WebSocket emitting a different kind of events for an entity Vehicle using adapter

1.Create a Vehicle-Socket-Adapter.ts

```
import { fromEvent, merge, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SocketIoService } from 'src/app/shared/services/socket-io.service';

export class VehicleSocketAdapter {
  public onVehicleEngineStateChange: Observable<boolean>;
  constructor(vehicleId: string, private socketIoService: SocketIoService) {

   //using merge from rxjs/operators to concat multiple ws events to one Observable 

    this.onVehicleEngineStateChange = merge(
      fromEvent(this.socketIoService.socket, `event.vehicle.${vehicleId}.start`).pipe(
        map(vehicleStatus => true)
      ),
      fromEvent(this.socketIoService.socket,`event.vehicle.${vehicleId}.stop`).pipe(
        map(vehicleStatus => false)
      ),
    )
  }
}
```

2.Later import the adapter wherever you would like to use, an example app.component.ts

```
private subscriptions = new Subscription();
private listenForVehiclesState(vehicles) {
    vehicles.forEach((vehicle) => {
      const vehicleAdapter = new VehicleSocketAdapter(vehicle.id, this.webSocket);
      this.subscriptions.add( 
        vehicleAdapter.onVehicleEngineStateChange.subscribe(vehicleStatus => {
        
       // dispatch action when adapter commands you

        this.store.dispatch(
          VehiclesActions.BeginUpdateVehiclesStatusAction({
            payload: {
              vehicleId: vehicle.id,
              status: vehicleStatus
            }
          })
        );

      }));
    });
  }
```

3. Don't forget to unsubscribe all subs when your view or a component is destroyed
   `this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();`

Bonus: Socket as service snippet :)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketIoService {

  public socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = io('/', { path: '/api/livedata', transportOptions: { polling: extraHeaders: {'AuthToken': 'ifAny'} }});

constructor() { }
}
```

Happy Coding :)